# What does this expression mean regarding pointers? Function Declaration

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list

```
void insertAtTail(node* &head ,int val);
```

where the `node` is a class name and head is pointing to the first element of the linked list.

I did not understand what does this mean

```
node* &head
```

Comment: And to explain what `node*& head` (or `node* &head` as written) means, it's a reference to a pointer to a `node` (a reference to `node*`).

Comment: It is similar (works like): `void insertAtTail(node**head ,int val);` it just hides one `*` in code.